# Why MQTT client doesn't reconnect correctly?

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have an MQTT client subscribing to a topic and to test all cases possible I turn off the broker and turn it on again to test for the automatic reconnection that MQTT provides and in the broker in verbose mode I can see that the client connects to the broker, but then nothing happens, there's no data flowing. Also, I noticed that the callback function on_connect does not get triggered even in the first connection before turning off the broker. In my publish client on_connect has also another strange behavior. It gets triggered but does not run all code inside the on_connect callback function and also I don't know why.
I am using mosquitto as broker.

I have tried using `qos > 0, keepalive=60, clean session = false` and none of these solves the problem of no data transmission and the `on_connect` function still does not get triggered.

The subscriber code looks like this:

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

broker_url = "127.0.0.1"

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   print("Connected With Result Code " (rc))
   client.subscribe("Magnetometer", qos=2)

def on_message_from_Magnetometer(client, userdata, message):
   print("Message Recieved from Magnetometer: "+message.payload.decode())

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
   print("Message Recieved from Others: "+message.payload.decode())

def on_log(mqttc, obj, level, string):
    print(string)

client = mqtt.Client(client_id='MagnetometerSubscriber', clean_session=False)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(broker_url, keepalive=60)

client.subscribe("Magnetometer", qos=2)
client.message_callback_add("Magnetometer", on_message_from_Magnetometer)


client.loop_forever()
```

The client code looks like this:

```py
client=""

flushOfflineData = 0

flag_connected = 0

flag_first_connection = 1

logger=''

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   global flag_connected
   print "Client connected with the Broker."
   flag_connected = 1
   print flag_first_connection

   #This code below does not get executed

   if flag_first_connection == 1:
      flag_first_connection = 0
   else:
      ParseOfflineData()

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
   global flag_connected
   flag_connected = 0
   setLocalStore()
   print "Client disconnected with the Broker."


def main():

    InitializeBrokerConnection()


    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/pts/17',\
        baudrate=9600,\

        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)

    print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)



    while True:

        line=ser.readline()
        if line:
            print(line)
            json_body=Parse(line)
            if flag_connected == 1:
               client.publish("Magnetometer",json_body, qos=2)
            else:
                StoreLocally()


    ser.close()


def InitializeBrokerConnection():
    global client
    broker_address="127.0.0.1" 

    client = mqtt.Client("Magnetometer")
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
    client.connect(broker_address) 
    client.loop_start()
```

So I was expecting the code of both `on_connect` functions to run and for the subscriber client to reconnect when possible and to start receiving data. This problem only appears when I turn off the broker and turn it on again to test if the subscriber connects and receives data. When I have the broker online and I execute the subscriber python code it works fine, but when I turn the broker offline and back online whith the subscriber client is running it does not receive data again.

Comment: if on_connect is never getting called then the client is not actually connecting. Have you looked at the broker logs to see if there are errors when it tries to connect?

Comment: I ran your code and it says     print("Connected With Result Code " (rc))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @GambitSupport I removed  the rc variable and now it works. I wonder why it does not throw me an error... now I still the problem in the publisher code that the if statement in on_connect is not executed. Does that mean I have an error before? But there's is only variable assigment it should not throw errors

Comment: @hardillb it was an error in the on_connect function. I was not aware of the error because it didn't throw an error for me and I don't know why

Comment: Feel free to post an answer to your own question (and accept it) so the question gets closed off